# Not able to see images in darknet

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying to do object detection using YOLO. For that I installed darknet. I'm using a system with cpu only. So in Makefile, I made opencv=1. There is opencv in my system but I'm not able to see the images. 
When I type the code-

```
./darknet imtest data/eagle.jpg
```

I'm getting:-

```
L2 Norm: 371.979095

Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Original.png instead 

Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Gray.png instead

Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C1.png instead

Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C2.png instead

Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C3.png instead

Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C4.png instead
```

I know it's the problem with opencv installation but I don't know how to overcome that. I tried to install opencv with package manager also. If someone have installed darknet properly, can you please explain me the steps. I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What darknet do you use: original from pjreddie or popular fork from AlexeyAB? In original may be problems with OpenCV. In darknet from AlexeyAB it works fine but it need some changes for the latest OpenCV: https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/pull/1348

Comment: I tried to use original from pjreddie

Comment: try `pkg-config --modversion opencv` what does it print? Darknet needs Opencv that run well with C/C++ code, not python